# Behavior synonyms?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

Should [behavior](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/behavior) and [misbehavior](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/misbehavior) be synonyms?  I can't imagine someone asking about behavior because of their concern over it being good.  Behavior has more associated questions, so having misbehavior point to behavior seems the way to go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Misbehavior is always behavior, but not necessarily the other way around.  I've used the [behavior](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/behavior) tag on questions like [How to inspire more creativity in play?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/11298/644) where the child wasn't behaving *badly*, just not in a way I understood.  This is reflected in the tag wiki:

> Questions about why children act the way they do. See the tag [discipline](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discipline) about enforcing your rules.

Part of enforcing your rules is understanding why children are acting the way they do, so there's a lot of overlap and the boundary isn't always strongly enforced.  Looking at the [misbehavior](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/misbehavior) questions, I think making it a synonym of [discipline](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discipline) might be more appropriate.

Comment: Good points and your conclusion is what I was trying to say with the "point to" statement -- you've stated it more clearly.